# Reindex data from Amazon S3 to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We have some GB's of data in the form of json files in Amazon S3 , we also index data in Elasticsearch for searching.
We want to have functionality  to reindex data in Elasticsearch for following reasons.

1] ES outage
2] New fields added/removed from document.

We tried reading data from s3 in our code and then sending it to ES , it was quite slow and cannot be used.

What is the best way to reindex data from Amazon S3 to Elasticsearch.

Regards,

Comment: The absolute minimum effort is piping the data from S3 to ES, which means reading S3 data and transferring to ES. Since S3 has no built-in scripting capabilities there needs to be an intermediate server that can mediate the transfer so, reading data and sending to ES is the absolute minimum that needs to be done. All you can do is optimize the read/write speeds e.g. by ensuring everything is within the same VPN/AWS region/account

Comment: Do you use ES from AWS? Or do you have your own ES?

Comment: Thanks jordivador ! We are using AWS Elasticsearch instance. as you suggested we need  an intermediate server that can mediate the transfer data from AWS S3 to ES can we use logstash for this purpose.
So basically Logstash will read data from AWS S3 files (1 by 1 or parallely) and will push it to  AWS ES